# Converting a popup window uploader to an inline script using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a few buttons in my script that call window.open('myUploadScript.php?arguments=test...','').

I'm passing querystring parameters in the arguments() for the target file myUploadScript.php to process.

I'd like to call this script without opening it in a popup. Can I use jQuery for this without having to start from scratch on my popup window script?

In other words, my window.open contains:

```
<input 
type="button" 
id="myButton" 
value="myValue" 
onclick="window.open('myUploadScript.php?action=test',
    'popup',
    'width=330,
    height=300,
    scrollbars=no,
    resizable=no,
    toolbar=no,
    directories=no,
    location=no,
    menubar=no,
    status=no'); 
    return false" 
/>
```

Can I instead call a jQuery that loads the contents of myUploadScript.php into a placeholder div, passing it the "test" argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it as other posters explained. However, if it's an actual file upload script, this will not help you.

The issue is that file upload doesn't work via AJAX (only works in select browsers, but not generally). The only way to implement ajax file upload in pure html/javascript is using iframe, like so:

```
    <form id="vinsearchform" target="upload_target" action="/Home/VINUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="filename" />
       <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <iframe style="display:none" id="upload_target" name="upload_target"></iframe>
```

What this does is post the upload into a hidden iframe. The iframe has to emit javascript which will tell the page that it's done, something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   window.top.window.uploadCompleted();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Artemiy, the file upload is done via PHP. I'm just trying to avoid opening the PHP uploader script in a popup window.

Comment: Yeah, my comment was not about server side though. You may not realize this, but clicking "upload" button (or whatever that's called in your case) from myfile.php will post your complete page. Which defeats the purpose of making this ajax. That is OK if you only want the form itself to be loaded using ajax (but posting not being ajax)

Comment: You may be right. I'm just starting to test and the form loads perfectly fine, but does not appear to actually upload or transfer the files as it does when its opened in a popup window.

Comment: You may have an issue with form inside a form. Are you injecting your myphp content into another form tag maybe?

Comment: Artemiy, after re-reading your comment, I need to clarify. The button on the calling page is just used to execute a popup window containing "myFile.php". There is an actual "upload" button contained inside of myFile.asp which triggers the file/dialog to browse for the file.

Comment: @Artimiy, yes. I probably should create another question to address that issue, since this one has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Use .[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#your_div').load( 'myFile.php?action=test' );
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. Looks simple enough. Checking it out now.

Answer (score 1):

Do an [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to that page instead:

```
//register click on input event
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    //do ajax call to your script
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myFile.php',
        data: { action: 'test' }, //adds a query string to the URL '?action=test'
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //data is the returned value from your .php script
            $('#divId').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //some error occurred you can handle it here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I accidently forgot to wrap the options sent to ajax in the object `{}` notation, my fault updated the answer.